# Wordpress custom content area with wp editor?

Tags: php, wordpress

Using my Wordpress theme functions file, I have created a custom meta text area (please see screenshot below).

The custom meta text area is displayed when editing a page.

[image]

It all works great saving and changing the text, but if i change a certain part of the paragraph text to heading2 and click save, it reverts the heading2 back to paragraph.

My functions update post meta box looks like the following:

```
if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text_challengetbl'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_text_challengetbl', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text_challengetbl'], $allowed ) );
}
```

The $allowed php code looks like the following:

```
$allowed = array( 
    'a' => array( // on allow a tags
        'href' => array() // and those anchords can only have href attribute
    )
);
```

Comment: Can you please let us see what the value of $allowed is please, that needs to contain "h2" etc

Comment: Hi Simon, yeah no problem, please see my question amended above with the value of $allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update...

```
$allowed = array( 
    'a' => array( // on allow a tags
        'href' => array() // and those anchords can only have href attribute
    ),
    'h2' => array()
);
```

This will allow H2 to be used, note: you can add in any other html tags you want allowed here as well. Check out https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses for more info.

Comment: Brilliant, many thanks for your answer this works. I was only allowing anchor tags to be added, as above I added the h2 tag which works perfectly.

Comment: Great stuff :) glad to be of help and like I said check out the link to see how to add more tags if you need them.